# Logging in to the Redis(Puts should go to redis)

Tags: ruby, logging, resque

I want a functionality to log my all "puts" to go to redis at the same time to STDOUT as well.

```
class Job
  def self.perform
    puts "Abc"
  end
end
```

Then I am expecting a key value pair in redis. if the job ID is 1

```
  Resque.redis.get("log_1")  #=> "Abc"
```

I need this because, So that another remote machine can read this logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need this because, So that another remote machine can read this logs.

You should try using a 'real' logging solution then, such as Graylog2.

Also, don't use `puts` for logging, use Resque.logger: https://github.com/resque/resque/blob/1-x-stable/lib/resque.rb#L473-L475

Comment: Hello Steve, Actually my app has been developed very much already, with few custom gems. So I needed to output my all the logs from all the code. Something similar to `log tail` functionality. I have resolved it already. I will paste my solution here. Bt your solution is more appt if I had complete control of the repo.